# How can I perform or process multiple operation on a single image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So here is my problem statement: I am providing certain operations to be performed on images in my editor like rotate, crop, resize, etc. These operations which I am performing on images provide a certain output that I am storing in my image data node to perform it on the image that is uploaded to S3 via a pre-signed URL. For example, on cropping the image I will get crop properties like x, y, width, and height from where I have to crop the original image, for rotate I get the angle, etc.

When an image is uploaded to S3 some of these properties are initialized by default and stored in the image data node. These properties are then changed when an operation respective to that is performed. The structure of properties that I am storing in the image is as follow:

```
const properties = {
    crop: {
      // Here x & y: position to place crop container of specific width & height mentioned below
      unit: '%',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    },
    rotate: 0 // Angle in degrees
  };
```

When a document is loaded in my editor then these properties of images are being accessed and then applied respectively in the operation to show it in front-end. The method I am using to apply these properties is the CANVAS method to generate a blob from the respective operation in order to show the processed image.

My main objective is to perform these operations on the original image with the properties I am getting from the operation. but with the increase in operations, the priority of sequence of operation is also essential in order to apply these properties to the original image correctly. For example, I have an original image, I rotate it 90 deg anticlockwise then applied the crop and then rotated back to its orientation so the crop parameter I am getting will be different to what I  have to apply on original image so keeping track of operation sequence is also essential over here. So I am also looking for a way by which I can store these operations sequences performed on the original image correctly so that I do not have to save the output image each and every time when an operation is being performed i.e to reduce API calls.

Answer (score 0):

AWS already official provides a solution named [Serverless Image Handler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/) which also provides image manipulation on air via S3, Lambda and CloudFront.

It provides similar functionalities you want. Also it's open source and supports one-click deployment into your account!

It's a good reference and production level implementation.